# Support both encrypted and non encrypted configuration with aumbry

Tags: python, configuration, python-cryptography, aumbry

We have a python application that loads a `config.yml` with **[aumbry](https://github.com/pyarmory/aumbry)**. For production purpose we need to encrypt this configuration with **[fernet](https://github.com/pyarmory/aumbry/blob/master/aumbry/cli/utils.py)**, which aumbry can load seamlessly.

We want to be able to load both unencrypted and encrypted in a transparent way, for example load unencrypted if found, and if not (production) load encrypted. So far we have implemented this.

### Encryption

```py
import cryptography.Fernet as fn
from os.path import split, splitext

def _encrypt_file(path, key):
    with open(path, 'rb') as infile:
        file_data = infile.read()
        nc_data= fn(key).encrypt(file_data)
        infile.close()

        base_path, filename = split(path)
        name, _ = splitext(filename)
        nc_name = "{}.{}".format(name, 'nc')
        with open(join(base_path, nc_name), 'wb') as outfile:
            outfile.write(nc_data)
            outfile.close()
```

### Aumbry configuration

```
from aumbry.errors import LoadError

def _get_configuration():
    return aumbry.load(
        aumbry.FILE,
        AppConfig,
        options={
            'CONFIG_FILE_PATH': "config.yml"            
        }
    )

def _get_encrypted_configuration():
    return aumbry.load(
        aumbry.FERNET,
        AppConfig,
        options={
            'CONFIG_FILE_PATH': "config.nc",
            'CONFIG_FILE_FERNET_KEY': 'bZhF6nN4A6fhVBPtru2dG1_6d7i0d_B2FxmsybjtE-g='
        }
    )
def load_config():
    """General method to load configuration"""
    try:
        return _get_configuration()
    except LoadError:
        try: 
            return _get_encrypted_configuration()
        except LoadError:
            return None
```

- Is there a more elegant way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the framework on which your python application is built, there is usually some kind of global "mode" value that can be used.

Flask, for example, uses `FLASK_ENV` environment variable that can be set to either `development` or `production`. Within the app, you can use

```
app.config['DEBUG']  # True if FLASK_ENV is "development"
```

to differentiate between the 2 modes.

In your case, the ambury loader can be refactored to do:

```
config_loader_cls = EncryptedConfigLoader if environment=='production' else PlainConfigLoader
```

I would go even further and have `EncryptedConfigLoader` fail if the configuration is *not encrypted* for additional security.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few solutions:

a) Encrypted files use different file names from its unencrypted counterparts. For example, an unencrypted file with the name "config.yml" may be renamed to "config_en.yml". This may not be your option.

b) I notice that "config.yml" normally has "version: 2" in its content. You just need to use Python to check if `"version:` is `in` the file, if so, it is unencrypted.